# PHP translation of python encryption function

Tags: php, python, encryption

I was trying to rewrite a python registration page of a game server to PHP,
before inserting the password to database it is encrypted with the following function

```
hash = binascii.b2a_hex(self.cipher.encrypt(binascii.a2b_hex(hash)))
```

I'm not familiar with encryption and have no clue how to translate this to PHP

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if the problem's been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's do this step by step.

Initially, the hexadecimal hash is converted to binary using the binascii's function a2b_hex. The PHP equivalent of that would be hex2bin.

Then, you're using cipher's encrypt function to, supposedly, encrypt the previously obtained value. This is one of your classes, so I can't really guess what it does. Go find out.

Finally, just use the reverse equivalent of PHP's hex2bin: bin2hex().

**PS**: this hashing procedure looks really, really, weird to me...